# GA4 Metric Aggregation by Custom Dimension over a Date Range?

Tags: php, google-analytics-4, php-analytics-data

I'm using the [php-data-analytics](https://github.com/googleapis/php-analytics-data) client library to return a [GA4 Pivot Report](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/pivots) and I'm trying to get results that looks like this:

[image: Pivot Table Example]

I want to return Aggregate Metrics for each `object_id` in each `dateRange`, but my request seems to return aggregates of both date ranges and not each separately. Here's what I currently have:

```
$args = array(
    "dimensions" => [
        new Dimension([ 'name' => 'nthDay' ]),
        new Dimension([ 'name' => 'streamId' ]),
        new Dimension([ 'name' => 'customEvent:listing_id' ])
    ],
    "metrics" => [
        new Metric([ 'name' => 'screenPageViews' ]),
        new Metric([ 'name' => 'activeUsers' ]),
        new Metric([ 'name' => 'userEngagementDuration' ])
        ],
    "dimensionFilter" => new FilterExpression([
        'filter' => new Filter([
            'field_name' => 'streamId',
            'string_filter' => new Filter\StringFilter([
                'match_type' => Filter\StringFilter\MatchType::EXACT,
                'value' => $stream_id,
            ])
        ])
    ]),
    "pivots" => [
        new Pivot([ 
            'field_names' => [ 'customEvent:listing_id', 'nthDay' ],
            "order_bys" => [
                new OrderBy([
                    'desc' => false,
                    'dimension' => new OrderBy\DimensionOrderBy([
                            "dimension_name" => 'customEvent:listing_id',
                            "order_type" => OrderBy\DimensionOrderBy\OrderType::NUMERIC
                    ])
                ]),
                new OrderBy([
                    'desc' => false,
                    'dimension' => new OrderBy\DimensionOrderBy([
                        "dimension_name" => 'nthDay',
                        "order_type" => OrderBy\DimensionOrderBy\OrderType::NUMERIC
                    ])
                ])
            ],
            'metric_aggregations' => [ MetricAggregation::TOTAL ],
            'limit' => 100
        ]),
        new Pivot([ 
            'field_names' => [ 'dateRange' ],
            'limit' => 100
        ])
    ]
);
```

How should I structure a [runPivortReport](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runPivotReport) request to produce the above report? Or is there a better way?

Comment: For somthing like traffic you'd need a data source that is not mentioned in your question, likely it will be somehow related to log-files or similar but it had to be clear first. Further thinkable properties like ranking by user-votes had the same problems: where it's stored, where the values come from?

Comment: Furthermore it might be important how you structure your code, if you do it in MVC style you'd likely use objects instead of data arrays.

Comment: please edit your question and add the snipet you have done and the error you are getting, so user who gives you ans has a clear understanding of the question

Comment: @FaizSandhi I'm not getting an error - I'm just not getting the aggregate results I'd like. I'm looking for help forming a pivot report request that would produce results like those in my example.

Comment: maybe you should add the code that produces partial result as a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I would say start simple to make it work without any complexity following [this example from the docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/pivots) using normal api and then build on top of it step by step till you reach your goal.
By the way, the example is showing a design that you are looking for.
And then convert the request body to your programming language (php).
Hopefully that will help you.

```html
POST https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/GA4_PROPERTY_ID:runPivotReport
  {
    "dateRanges": [{ "startDate": "2020-09-01", "endDate": "2020-09-15" }],
    "dimensions": [
        { "name": "browser" },
        { "name": "country" },
        { "name": "language" }
      ],
    "metrics": [{ "name": "sessions" }],
    "pivots": [
      {
        "fieldNames": [
          "browser"
        ],
        "limit": 5
      },
      {
        "fieldNames": [
          "country"
        ],
        "limit": 250
      },
      {
        "fieldNames": [
          "language"
        ],
        "limit": 15
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: I've done this. The issue arises when I try to get aggregate results for a custom dimension across multiple date ranges. For example, I want activeUsers with objectID `1` for date_range_0 and, as another value, date_range_1 - it always combines these values.